# Changing yaxis number format in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So I've stumbled across a problem that I can't really understand how to solve. I've got my graph made, and my yaxis has numbers that reach milions. The problem is that i get exponential values (1e6) instead of the whole numbers. I'd like to see milions, instead of exponential values. This is the graph:

[image: Graph with exponential values]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found this documentation inside the matplotlib site https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html. I suppose you need to set the second attribute to `plain`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was indeed the plain attribute. I've tried 3 different methods and I thought it just couldn't be, you saved me on this one. Thank you again <3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TheOldJonny I could figure it out, and what worked for me was this 2 lines of code:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')
```